# python change Jun to June

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I take the tomorrows date like this

```
tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            self.FirstDateString = str(tomorrow.strftime("%d %b %Y"))
```

and the result is `11 Jun 2014`

I parse it like this:

```
datetime.strptime('11 Jun 2014', "%d %B %Y").date()
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: time data '11 Jun 2014' does not match format '%d %B %Y'
```

but when I change `Jun` to `June`, it works.

So, how can I tell the `tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)` to give me `June` instead of `Jun`

#### in my case I will have both Jun and June so I would prefer to change Jun to June to make everything works

Comment: You are **parsing an input string**. You have to use the right formatters to do so. What has that got to do with `datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`?

Comment: If you are **formatting an output string**, then talk about that instead.

Comment: Why don't you just change `%B` to `%b`, or did I miss something.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry I didn't userstand u, could u clear please?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I will try and update u

Comment: @BurhanKhalid when I do that, the `Jun` works, but the `June` gives error that the format is not correct

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: What, if anything, has the `datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)` code have to do with your `datetime.strptime()` problem?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: so are you saying you have to parse dates from a mixed dataset that has dates with both abbreviated months and fully spelled out months? Again, I don't get what the *today + 1 day* calculation has to do with all this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the `today +1` is to give me the `tomorrow`. and yes i have both jun and june in my application so I would prefer to change the check if jun then  change it to june then parsing it. I think it is issue with string not with format right? all the users understood me wrong, they think that i am asking about why the exception happnes, my english is bad to descrip to them

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: The `tomorrow` part is distracting. It has nothing to do with your question, whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understand the issue. You don't need to convert the datetime object to a string first:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%d %b %Y'))
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(today, '%d %B %Y'))
```

This will give you:

```
10 Jun 2014
10 June 2014
```

Now, if your problem is that you have some strings and want to convert them, but some have `Jun` and others `June`, you don't have a choice but to try it one way, and if it doesn't work, try it the other way:

```
try:
    obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(some_string, '%d %b %Y')
except ValueError:
    # It didn't work with %b, try with %B
    try:
        obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(some_string, '%d %B %Y')
    except ValueError:
        # Its not Jun or June, eeek!
        raise ValueError("Date format doesn't match!")
print('The date is: {0.day} {0.month} {0.year}'.format(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`%b` format code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for abbreviated month names:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> datetime.strptime('11 Jun 2014', "%d %B %Y").date()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '11 Jun 2014' does not match format '%d %B %Y'
>>>
>>> datetime.strptime('11 Jun 2014', "%d %b %Y").date()
datetime.date(2014, 6, 11)
>>>
```

Comment: in my application, I have both `Jun` and `June`

Comment: so I would prefer to change the Jun to June and this way everything willwork